# Colorbox changing close button image

Tags: jquery, html, css, colorbox

I'm trying to change JackMoore's colorbox. At first I wanted to change the close (x) button. But now I realize the X button doesn't even show up. I've done a bunch of modifications, like getting rid of the overlay and expanding the window size.

I want to put the X in the top right corner...

Like the example "inline html"
http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example2/#inline_content

These were sections I modified but now I'm not sure why I can't get it to show.. not even the default..

```
#cboxOverlay{position:fixed; width:0%; height:0%;} 
#cboxPrevious, #cboxNext, #cboxSlideshow, #cboxClose {border:0; padding:0; margin:0; overflow:visible; text-indent:-9999px; width:20px; height:20px; position:absolute; top:-20px; background:url('images/map-yellow-dot.gif') no-repeat 0 0;}
```

I replaced the close button with the yellow dot above.

I thought I needed this to move the title box up to the top.. but it doesn't seem to do anything

```
#colorbox #cboxClose
{
top: 0;
right: 0;
}
#cboxLoadedContent{
margin-top:28px;
margin-bottom:0;
}
```

Here's my colorbox.js.. made mods in there too

```
transition: "elastic",
        speed: 300,
        fadeOut: 300,
        width: '70%',
        initialWidth: "50%", 
        innerWidth: false,
        maxWidth: '75%',
        height: '100%',
        initialHeight: "50%",  
        innerHeight: false,
        maxHeight: '100%',
        scalePhotos: true,
        scrolling: false,
        opacity: 0.1,
        preloading: true,
        className: false,
        overlayClose: false,
        escKey: true,
        arrowKey: true,
        top: '10%',
        bottom: false,
        left: '24%',
        right: false,
        fixed: false,
        data: undefined,
        closeButton: true,
        fastIframe: true,
        open: false,
        reposition: true,
        loop: true,
        slideshow: false,
        slideshowAuto: true,
        slideshowSpeed: 2500,
        slideshowStart: "start slideshow",
        slideshowStop: "stop slideshow",
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what is exactly you want? you want to change close button to custom image? and you want to reduce top space in colorbox, Isn't?

Comment: well i want to be able to use my own image for the X button. But I guess first, I need my X button to show..as it's not

Answer (score 0):

We can move the colorbox close button to the top right. Just use the following CSS style to move the close button to the top right.

```
<style>
    #colorbox #cboxClose {
        top: 0 !important;
        right: 0 !important;
    }
    #cboxLoadedContent {
        margin-top:28px !important;
        margin-bottom:0 !important;
    }
</style>
```

I've used the above code to fix the issue on my scenario.